# Filter lines from a text file which contain a particular word

Tags: python, filter, line

I want to write a program which filters the lines from my text file which contain the word "apple" and write those lines into a new text file.

What I have tried just writes the word "apple" in my new text file, whereas I want whole lines.

Answer (score 36):

Use can get all lines containing 'apple' using a list-comprehension:

```
[ line for line in open('textfile') if 'apple' in line]
```

So - also in one code-line - you can create the new textfile:

```
open('newfile','w').writelines([ line for line in open('textfile') if 'apple' in line])
```

And eyquem is right: it's definitely faster to keep it as an iterator and write

```
open('newfile','w').writelines(line for line in open('textfile') if 'apple' in line)
```

Comment: A list comprehension creates an object. Using a generator expression would be better. By the way it can be written ``writelines( line for line in open('textfile') if 'apple' in line) ``

Comment: @eyquem: Ok, I totally agree that -- for large files -- it should be the better to use generators, since a generator behaves lazily and thus doesnt consume that much memory. But probably for small files the list-comprehension is the faster solution?

Comment: @Phynfo: Nope... keeping things as generators/iterators is far more efficient. The list comprehension is still creating the iterator, which is then filling a list, and once complete passing that list to writelines which turns it back into an iterator.

Comment: Can I use multiple strings here to match?
Ex: I want to retain only line with string 'apple' or 'orange'

Comment: You can replace `if 'apple' in line` with `if 'apple' in line or 'orange' in line`

Answer (score 12):

```
from itertools import ifilter

with open('source.txt','rb') as f, open('new.txt','wb') as g:
    g.writelines(ifilter(lambda line: 'apple' in line, f))
```

Comment: Be aware that `itertools.ifilter` has been removed in Python 3.5+, and is replaced with the built-in `filter`https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter, which is equivalent to the generator expression in the answer of phynfo .

Answer (score 11):

Using generators, this is memory efficient and fast

```
def apple_finder(file):
    for line in file:
        if 'apple' in line:
             yield line


source = open('forest','rb')

apples = apple_finder(source)
```

I love easy solutions with no brain damage for reading :-)

Comment: The function **apple_finder(file)** is a function generator and **apples** is a generator. The latter do the same job as **ifilter(lambda line: 'apple' in line, f)** in two lines (import comprised)

Answer (score 6):

For **Python3** - here is working and fast example

```
    text = b'line contains text'
    with open('input.txt', 'rb') as file_in:
        with open('output.txt', 'wb') as file_out:
            file_out.writelines(
                filter(lambda line: text in line, file_in)
            )
```

### Tests:

input.txt:

```
Test line contains text
Not line not contains this text

HEY
Another line contains text
```

output.txt:

```
Test line contains text
Another line contains text
```

### More about code:

`b'line contains text'` - the `b` states for `binary` and we operating on this kind of string skipping some problems with encoding etc.
Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=binary#bytes-objects

`rb` `wb` - operating on `read` and `write` operation with `binary` like objects
Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o

`filter()` - takes `expression` and `iterable object`. Returns filtered object. In our example `filter` takes all lines (`iterable object`) and apply for each line `lambda` what inform `filter` if given `line` should be returned or not.

`lambda` - contains two elements `argument`: `expression`. In our example `lambda` check if `line` contains given `text`. Return `True` or `False` after `expression` check.

Example with `lambda` and `filter`: https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-filter-in-python-using-lambda-functions/

Answer (score 2):

`if "apple" in line:` should work.