# Filter txt lines that start with a specific string (Python)

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
...
|J150|DRE.16.2|T|2|DRE.16|PROVISAO P  CSLL|6779,24|D|D||
|J150|DRE.16.2.001|D|3|DRE.16.2|CSLL|6779,24|D|D||
|J150|DRE.17|T|1||LUCRO DO EXERCICIO|55797,1|C|R||
|J005|01012018|31122018|1||
|J100|BP.01|T|1||A|ATIVO|5540527,48|D|8656252,32|D||
|J100|BP.01.1|T|2|BP.01|A|ATIVO CIRCULANTE|5030370,68|D|7881200,94|D||
|J100|BP.01.1.1|T|3|BP.01.1|A|DISPONIBILIDADES|380741,7|D|777224,63|D||
|J100|BP.01.1.1.01|T|4|BP.01.1.1|A|CAIXA|96786,62|D|69935,41|D||
|J100|BP.01.1.1.01.001|D|5|BP.01.1.1.01|A|Caixa|96786,62|D|69935,41|D||
...
```

It is quite long. I want to separate in a new file only the lines that start with "|J100|". I've tried some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245058/python-filter-lines-from-a-text-file-which-contain-a-particular-word) but didn't work in my case. Below my trials:

```
path="file.txt"
open('newfile','w').writelines([ line for line in open(path) if '|J100|' in line])
```

Didn't work, got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 255: invalid start byte`

Then I tried this one:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f,open('new.txt','wb') as g:
    g.writelines(filter(lambda line: '|J100|' in line, f))
```

And got this as response: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `b'|J100|' in line` or `'|J100|' in str(line)`

Comment: str(line) worked perfectly! thanks!

Comment: The proper solution is to figure out the actual encoding, or clean out data which cannot be properly interpreted. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 0):

If

```
path="file.txt"
open('newfile','w').writelines([ line for line in open(path) if '|J100|' in line])
```

raises a `UnicodeDecodeError` then the contents of file.text are not encoded as UTF-8.

This code

```
with open(path,'rb') as f,open('new.txt','wb') as g:
    g.writelines(filter(lambda line: '|J100|' in line, f))
```

raises a `TypeError` because you are reading the file in binary mode, so its contents are output as [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), but the lambda is comparing these bytes to a string value (`'|J100|'`).  The best approach is to compare bytes with bytes (`b'|J100|'`).  Also, if you only want lines that begin with a specific value, use [bytes.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.startswith) to filter lines that contain the |J100| after the start:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f,open('new.txt','wb') as g:
    g.writelines(filter(lambda line: line.startswith(b'|J100|'), f))
```